# Python web scraping requests keep getting robot

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I try to web scrape the following pages it keeps thinking I'm a bot => `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">`, even when I am passing custom headers:

- https://www.funda.nl/koop/rotterdam/huis-41854562-rutger-metelerkamppad-14/
- https://www.funda.nl/koop/rotterdam/

How can I bypass this? See code below:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua=UserAgent();
hdr = {'User-Agent': ua.random,
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

url = 'https://www.funda.nl/koop/rotterdam/'
urlresponse = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)

print(urlresponse.text[:1000])
```

Comment: ```Disallow: /koop/*,*``` do it at your own risk.

Comment: @DainiusPreimantas Thanks for pointing that out. This is just for my personal knowledge, I have no commercial intention or anything in that direction

Comment: Try using a valid User-Agent .. User-Agent from ua.random() doesn't always work

Comment: @SharyarVohra Hi, I've tried different static user agents including my own when I visit the site normally but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving me a clear understanding of which sort of data you're trying to scrape from the site but more than often is the prices with respective house or similar a primary goal. Which you could retrieve through the following. I made a few changes:

```html
import requests
import re
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua=UserAgent()

hdr = {'User-Agent': ua.random,
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

url = 'https://www.funda.nl/zoeken/koop/?selected_area=%5B%22rotterdam%22%5D'
urlresponse = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)

res = str(urlresponse.content)
prices = re.findall(r'ata-test-id="price-sale" class="font-semibold">\\n        \\xe2\\x82\\xac (.*?) k\.k\.\\n', res)
print(prices)
```

With the output:

```html
['419.500', '350.000', '499.500', '450.000', '439.000', '275.000', '335.000', '275.000', '215.000', '550.000', '325.000', '264.500', '339.000', '239.000', '615.000']
```

And if you want the street names too, you just create a regular expression for that instead. And of course if you want other information from the page, you just use the variable `res` to find that or alternitevly the text version `res = str(urlresponse.text)` since you used that from the start.